# When Assigning different value to a scope and just call one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to write for the first time with AngularJS and I'm not a developer at all.
I'm very beginning at programming.

Here's my problem;
I want in `var ouinon` assign to the `$scope.colors`, the value of the selected color input by the user in front-office.

Of course putting `$scope.colors.name` doesn't work... (in console.log, it's "undefined")

It may seem easy to you, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

JS Part:

```
function LookCtrl($scope, $http){

    $scope.colors = [
        {name:'blue', shade:'femme'},
        {name:'red', shade:'femme'},
        {name:'yellow', shade:'femme'},
        {name:'blue', shade:'homme'},
        {name:'red', shade:'homme'}
    ];

    $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2];  

    var ouinon = "http://api.shopstyle.fr/api/products?pid=uid7689-25635133-51&cat="
        + $scope.colors.name + "&limit=60&fl=d0&sort=Popular";

    $http.get(ouinon).success(function(data){
        $scope.look = data;
    });
```

HTML Part:

```
<section ng-controller="LookCtrl" ng-init="init()" class="panel panel-padding left" 
    ng-class="{center:panel==1, right:panel<1}">
    <h1>Selection: </h1>
    <select ng-model="myColor" 
        ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colors">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

Your `$scope.MyColor` is bound to the color that is selected.

You can use `$scope.MyColor.name` to get the name.

Also, I think you are writing the controller incorrectly. It seems that what you are trying to achieve is to make an Ajax call to get some data, but what is the trigger to get the data? If it is based on when selection changes, then you should write your controller as follows:

```
.controller("LookCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.colors = [
        {name:'blue', shade:'femme'},
        {name:'red', shade:'femme'},
        {name:'yellow', shade:'femme'},
        {name:'blue', shade:'homme'},
        {name:'red', shade:'homme'}
    ];

    $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // default selection

    $scope.onChange = function(){
        var ouinon = "http://api.shopstyle.fr/api/products?pid=uid7689-25635133-51&cat="
        + $scope.MyColor.name + "&limit=60&fl=d0&sort=Popular";

        $http.get(ouinon).success(function(data){
           $scope.look = data;
           $scope.$apply(); // this is needed since it's an async call
        }
    };

}]);
```

Then the HTML:

```
<section ng-controller="LookCtrl" ng-init="init()" class="panel panel-padding left" 
    ng-class="{center:panel==1, right:panel<1}">
    <h1>Selection: </h1>
    <select ng-model="myColor" ng-change="onChange()"
        ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colors">
    </select>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello New Dev, your code work for me. And thank you for the trigger, I haven't thought about it :)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms,  The  $scope.colors is an array, The $scope.colors.name is wrong grammar, could you write wrong, you should use $scope.MyColor.Name

Answer (score 0):

Try this one bro..

**Controller**

```
$scope.colors = [
           { name: 'blue', shade: 'femme' },
           { name: 'red', shade: 'femme' },
           { name: 'yellow', shade: 'femme' },
           { name: 'blue', shade: 'homme' },
           { name: 'red', shade: 'homme' }
    ];

    $scope.LookCtrl = function() {

        var ouinon = "http://api.shopstyle.fr/api/products?pid=uid7689-25635133-51&cat="
            + $scope.myColor + "&limit=60&fl=d0&sort=Popular";

        $http.get(ouinon).success(function (data) {
            $scope.look = data;
        });
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors" ng-change="LookCtrl()">
</select>
```

It is just a sample based on your problem but i dont get where you used `$scope.look` but in my example there it contain some data from the request.

I hope it will help you.

i let my `$scope.colors` declare outside the function (but obviously inside the controller) so that when the `select` is change the function of calling the api is trigger..

For further question just ask me and Im open to your questions